# Get specifics value from chain in PHP

Tags: php

My chain in PHP is like the following:

```
$chain = "m=toto&i=12&a=new";
```

How to get `m`, `i` and `a` values ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
<?php
$chain = "m=toto&i=12&a=new";
parse_str($chain,$array);
```

This will create an array named `$array` containing all values you can access them as `$array['m']`
You can Print all this by:

```
print_r($array);
```